# Происхождение слова "бумага"

Tags: этимология

Подумалось: во многих языках (в частности, в романских и в английском) слово "бумага" звучит родственно слову "папирус": the paper, la papel (если не путаю, что это женский род) и т.д. При этом в русском слове "бумага" "папирус" не угадывается никак.
Тогда каково происхождение русского слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположительно от итал. bombagia < лат. bombacium ‘хлопок’, первоисточником же считается иранский

Answer (score 2):

Слово ''Бумага'' восходит к иранскому : там ''памб***а***к'' означало издавна хлопок. попав через  Грецию в Италию, это ''памбак'' превратилось в " бомб***а***джо": так стали называть тут хлопчатую бумагу, хлопчатое волокно. На Русь х/т, а с ними и их название, были занесены именно итальянскими купцами. Похоже, что первым пришло к нам не слово ''бумага", а слово "бумажник" - так стали называть изготовленные из нового материала попоны, потники для лошадей; это древнее " бумажник" и было переработкой итальянского ''бомбаджо" на русский лад.  Так или иначе, слово ''бумага" русские люди узнали сперва как ''хлопчатая бумага". Лишь позже оно стало обозначать и бумагу писчую: ведь ее вырабатывали в старину из лоскутков различных льняных и хлопчатых тканей. 
***Лев Успенский. Почему не иначе. Этимологический словарь школьника. Изд. "Детская литература". М. , 1967г***.

Answer (score 0):

БУМАГА: Б - божественная, У - относится к, принадлежит, М - живородящее существо, ГА - дорога = божественная дорога живородящего существа. 
ПАПИРУС: П - охранение, А - начало, азы, первое, РУС - русский = стремление к сохранение начал русов.

Comment: В рамочку и на стену.

Answer (score 0):

Эстонская и вообще угро-финская семантика может оказаться верной, с учетом переходов Г-Т-Б-П. Учитывая старинную технологию производства бумаги, связанную с измельчением сырца (целлюлозы, хлопка, тряпья и т.п.), наиболее вероятная этимология:
Ст.-слав. и цер.-слав GUMAT или HOUMAT – толочь, откуда серб.-хорв. Gumati – пожирать, лопать. 
В чеш. это gumat – толочь, пихать, дергать и проч.
Отсюда, вероятно, русское «простанародное» ГУМАГА.